# How does one interpret the results of analysis with mixed model with baseline performance as random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

In a RCT investigating motor skill learning after stroke, patients were randomly allocated to 2 different groups ( i.e. with and without an intervention which was a robotic assistance during training). When we plot the raw data, because of the heterogeneity of the patients, although being randomized, the group receiving the intervention had a significantly higher performance at the baseline.

Since the study design included multiple time points and multiple measurements on each time point, we used mixed model (GLMM) for the data analysis. In order to take into account the difference in the baseline performance of two groups, we modeled the baseline score of each patient as the random effect in the model. Fixed effects were time, intervention and the interaction betweem them.

Now my question is that in interpretation of our data analysis, is it correct to say the results of our study have not been affected by the patients' heterogeneity since we added their baseline performance (i.e. baseline score) as the random effect?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please can you update the question to give some more background and details about your study and it's design...

Comment: To whomever downvoted this question without a comment: remember..."Maral is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct."

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you very much for your comments. Indeed, I am a very new contributor and in my effort to ask a concise question, it became difficult to understand it. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: If you want to compare your model with a baseline model (only intercept) then you can use an ANOVA to get the p-value (comparing logLikelihood estimates or AIC).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

- Random effects are typically included to account for heterogeneity and correlations in the outcome for a specific grouping factor. For example, in your study, it seems that you have as a grouping factor the patients for whom you have multiple measurements over time. To account for the correlation in the repeated measurements of each patient you use the random effects. You also wrote that per time you have multiple measurements. Perhaps then you could also consider a nested random effect. Say for example, that per time point you do a measurement in both eyes of a patient. You expect that first measurements on the same patient are correlated, but also that perhaps measurements on the same eye are more correlated than measurements in different eyes.
- If you have systematic differences at baseline, you can add the main effect of treatment in your model. This will then capture the differences between the two groups at baseline. But perhaps still you may only want to test for differences between the two groups over time (see also the point below).
- Testing for differences at baseline is not very meaningful if you have done randomization. For more on this, check the following paper of Stephen Senn: [Testing for baseline balance in clinical trials](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e834/97a00c43c5924617ceaccc73840761d4564d.pdf).